# How to properly encrypt my whole system using VeraCrypt

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, veracrypt

When I'm trying to encrypt the system using System -> Encrypt System Partition/Drive I get an error saying, Windows does not appear to be installed on the drive from which it boots. This is not supported. Is there any way to safely encrypt most of my data from the drives without having to move or edit partitions?

Or is it easy to make windows boot from C using a tool or a utility?

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vs3z.png)

[Those are my drives and partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJpRN.png)

Comment: Did you delete your original question?  Please provide a screenshot of your partition layout and edit your question.

Comment: No this is the original question, the screenshot is in the link below the question.

Comment: One of your secondary drives has the system attribute.  Is there a reason?

Comment: Drive F is just used for my backup files so there is no reason, this was done automatically when I installed the drive.